# How do I intercept a request after all redirects are resolved but before page download with urllib2?

Tags: python, http, redirect, urllib2

I'm scraping news articles and using urllib2. It automatically handles redirects, and I can get the resolved url from the response with geturl()

But I want to stop the request if the resolved url is on a certain list, to avoid spending time and bandwidth downloading the page.

Answers to any of these questions would be sufficient

Does `urllib.opener.open()` download the page, or does that occur when you call `response.read()`?

Is there a method to ask `urllib2` just to resolve redirects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some quick and dirty experiments, I guess I can say I found a partial answer to your question. `opener.open()` and `urlopen()` both behave the same way by default. They will download the page to which you redirected, even if you can only read the output via the `read()` function.

However, you can override these defaults by using your own handlers, passed to `build_opener()`. For example, to make redirects to some URLs fail, you could do something similar to this, by subclassing the [HTTPRedirectHandler](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler):

```
class MyRedirectHandler(urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler):
    def http_error_302(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
        if fp.geturl().startswith('http://www.facebook.com/'):
            # This will raise an exception similar to this:
            # urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 302: FOUND
            return None
        else:
            # Let the default handling occur
            return super(MyRedirectHandler, self).http_error_302(req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
```

You would use it this way:

```
opener = urllib2.build_handler(MyRedirectHandler)
try:
    fp = opener.open(url)
except urllib2.HTTPError:
    content = None
    print 'This URL is not allowed or something'
else:
    content = fp.read()
```

Of course you would have to have the calling block in a try/except block to catch that exception. I guess there might be a way to overcome this, and let the handling be nicer, but I'm not sure.

Anyway, you check the docs [here](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.BaseHandler.http_error_nnn) for more details.

Hope it helps.

**EDIT**:

Actually, you might want to override `redirect_request` which covers other redirect codes also (not only 302). According to [this](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler.redirect_request), it should be the way to go.

Comment: how can I determine whether a given request is the final redirect? redirect_request gets called for every redirect (there can be more than one, and it's somewhat common on news sites)

Comment: You can't know when it's the last one, unless you read the last one. That's because the redirection is done via headers, which cannot be downloaded without the actual content (as far as I know). One thing you could do is stop redirecting when the page URL you are expecting is reached, only if you expect to see a specific pattern in the last URL (for example /news/xxxx/xxxx, that's it, stop redirection).